# Fail to set width and height for Vega-Lite

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visualization, vega

I am resizing Vega visualization by mouse drag.

My approach is to wrap Vega visualization by  and set width and height to `container`. This approach is described in the [official doc](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#specifying-responsive-width-and-height):

> You can set the top-level width or height properties to "container" to
>   indicate that the width or height of the plot should be the same as
>   its surrounding container.

I have tried but visualization fails to resize itself to its surrounding container. The visualization is very small:

It seems I have successfully set div to `<div style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">`, but canvas failed to set itself to surrounding container `<canvas width="76" height="36" class="marks" style="width: 38px; height: 18px;"></canvas>`

Code:

```
import { VegaLite } from 'react-vega'
import React, { useState } from "react";

var specDefault = {
  width: "container",
  height: "container",
  mark: 'bar',
  encoding: {
    x: { field: 'a', type: 'ordinal' },
    y: { field: 'b', type: 'quantitative' },
  },
  data: { name: 'table' },
}

const barData = {
  table: [
    { a: 'A', b: 28 },
    { a: 'B', b: 55 },
    { a: 'C', b: 43 },
    { a: 'D', b: 91 },
    { a: 'E', b: 81 },
    { a: 'F', b: 53 },
    { a: 'G', b: 19 },
    { a: 'H', b: 87 },
    { a: 'I', b: 52 },
  ],
}

function Visulization() {
  return (
    <>
      {VegaOutput()}
    </>
  )
}

  return (
    <>
      {SetMark()}
      {SetName()}
    </>
  )
}

function VegaOutput() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '800px', height: '800px' }}>
      <VegaLite spec={specDefault} data={barData} />
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {Visulization()}
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Error:

```html
<div style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"><div class="vega-embed has-actions" role="graphics-document" aria-roledescription="visualization" aria-label="Vega visualization"><canvas width="76" height="36" class="marks" style="width: 38px; height: 18px;"></canvas><form class="vega-bindings"></form><details title="Click to view actions"><summary>
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  <circle r="2" cy="8" cx="2"></circle>
  <circle r="2" cy="8" cx="8"></circle>
  <circle r="2" cy="8" cx="14"></circle>
</svg></summary><div class="vega-actions"><a href="#" target="_blank" download="visualization.svg">Save as SVG</a><a href="#" target="_blank" download="visualization.png">Save as PNG</a><a href="#">View Source</a><a href="#">View Compiled Vega</a><a href="#">Open in Vega Editor</a></div></details></div></div>
```